# How to .tar multiple text files

Tags: tar

I have multiple text files in a folder. I must tar them in a single tar-file. I am passing (iterate) the file names through a variable. When I do that only the first file gets tarred.

Here is the code/script:

```
"tar -czf "+filename_+TalendDate.getDate("MMddyyyy")+".tar.gz "+((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_3_CURRENT_FILE"))
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the script you are currently using.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I have included the code/script

Comment: Any specific reason why a `tar cf mytarball.tar *.txt` cannot be used?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it, all the files are actually being tarred, but they're actually overwriting each other. Simply, it can't be done the way you're trying, but you have two options:

1. Concatenate all the filenames together and call tar exactly once with all of them. This is the cleaner method.
2. Use replace (r) or update (u) flags to enable appending to the archive. To do so, you must disable compression (remove z flag).

Comment: Thanks for replying BowlesCR, Could you please explain the first option. I didn't understand it as I am new to this.

Comment: I'm not sure what language you're scripting in, but effectively rework your script to do `tar czf file.tgz A B C` instead of trying to do `tar czf file.tgz A`, `tar czf file.tgz B`, `tar czf file.tgz C`